# Python: write Dataframe to influxdb

Tags: python, dataframe, influxdb

I just started using the influxdb client in python. I'm trying to write a Dataframe to influxdb. Based on

> https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#tutorials-pandas

I can doing this using DataFrameClient.

my data:

```
                              Val1        Val2       S_id   Formula
          Date              
2020-01-01 01:00:00+00:00   26.131181   12.537605   35211   soneja
2020-01-01 01:15:00+00:00   21.459827   10.671435   35211   soneja
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2020-01-21 00:45:00+00:00   13.257205   4.322372    35211   soneja
2020-01-21 01:00:00+00:00   13.520987   4.393989    35211   soneja

1901 rows × 4 columns
```

my code to ship data into influxdb:

```
from influxdb import DataFrameClient
client = DataFrameClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
client.write_points(df, dbname, protocol='line')
```

The error I got:

```
('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is related to your influxdb setup and network. For me this works:

```py
from influxdb import DataFrameClient
client = DataFrameClient(host="localhost", port=8086)
client.create_database("data")
client.write_points(
    df,
    "measurement1",
    database="data",
    protocol="line",
    batch_size=1000,
)
```